# Richer question highlighting color when matches multiple favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-highlighting

(*Note: In the following post I'll use `FT = favorite tags`.*)

When you prefer a tag, all the questions tagged with it are highlighted in the main page. When you prefer multiple tags all the questions that have *at least* one of the FT are highlighted.

Wouldn't it make more sense to make it so that the color intensity is determined by the number of FT there are in a specific question compared to the total number?

For example, with the following FT:

```
[ c++ ] [ mysql ] [ cgi ] [ design-pattern ]
```

A question with:

```
[ c++ ] [ mysql ] [ database ] [ design-pattern ] [ dependency-injection ]
```

would have the highlight color opacity set to:

```
[opacity] = [# of favorite tags in question] / [total # of favorite tags]
          = 3 / 4
          = 0.75
```

The background color would match more the interest of the user for a particular question.

What do you think?

Comment: @LanceRoberts, the question you linked hasn't an accepted answer. Actually it doesn't have an answer at all.

Comment: feature-requests don't really need answers, though they will often get them, usually for modifications or justifications of the feature request.  I'm surprised that the system allowed me to case a close-as-duplicate vote when it didn't have an answer though.  Personally I think it's a good idea, and you should paste your justification (example) in as an answer to that question, then maybe tomorrow put a bounty on it.